# Why is requestAnimFrame being called 2 times?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm following along [this](http://joshondesign.com/p/books/canvasdeepdive/chapter04.html#settimeout) book to learn about html5 canvas animations, and I was wondering, in this code:

```
// shim layer with setTimeout fallback 
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){ 
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||  
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||  
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||  
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||  
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||  
          function( callback ){ 
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60); 
          }; 
})();

var x = 0; 
function drawIt() { 
    window.requestAnimFrame(drawIt); 
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
    c.fillStyle = "red"; 
    c.fillRect(x,100,200,100); 
    x+=5; 
} 
window.requestAnimFrame(drawIt);
```

Why is `window.requestAnimFrame(drawIt)` being called both outside and inside drawIt function?

Comment: The bottom call triggers the drawIt loop to start.  The call inside the drawIt loop causes the loop to continue.

Comment: The one outside the `drawIt` function is like the ignition. Without it, then the cycle of animation wouldn't start.

Comment: BTW, [there's no such thing as `oRequestAnimationFrame` or `msRequestAnimationFrame`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe). You can remove those.

Comment: I see... But, calling it from the outsite isn't saying already that the `drawIt` function will be called every frame? Why then call again inside the function?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` adds a callback function for the next time a frame is drawn. You need to add it initially, then again after each frame draw.

Comment: Each requestAnimationFrame executes the loop only once.  Therefore it is continually called inside the loop to keep the loop running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on what most have already stated in comments (with some additional tips) -

`requestAnimationFrame` does a single asynchronous call to the function passed in as an argument. This means the method needs to be called continuously to create an animation loop.

The logic place to invoke the call to update the next frame is from within the loop itself. However, the loop is merely a function and needs to be invoked as well, so an initial call is required to "start" the loop. (For this reason it is also wise to consider a mechanism to break the loop).

Another technique could be to use a self-invoking call. The code would in that case look like this instead, without the initial call:

```
(function drawIt() { 
    window.requestAnimFrame(drawIt); 
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
    c.fillStyle = "red"; 
    c.fillRect(x,100,200,100); 
    x+=5; 
})();
```

The function inside first pair of parenthesis is evaluated while the second pair will invoke a call for whatever is evaluated, ie. the function. If you chose this or the original is more or less a matter of personal taste (the first frame is not updated until the first next available monitor refresh anyways so you won't have any glitches doing a manual update the first time).

Another thing worth noticing while at it: obtaining references to canvas and context is usually never done *inside* a loop as they are relative costly operations. Try to always obtain those outside the loop, and only once:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
var c = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

(function drawIt() { 
    window.requestAnimFrame(drawIt); 
    c.fillStyle = "red";       // also a potential candidate for optimizing
    c.fillRect(x,100,200,100); 
    x+=5; 
})();
```

If you set color only once, this too could be moved outside the loop (ie. `fillStyle`, `strokeStyle` etc.). These are also costly in terms of animation.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. I'm accepting as the right one.